# Difference between su and su -

Tags: su

I wonder what's the exact difference between these 2 commands:1. su
2. su - . Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

The man page describes it fairly well with the following:

```
   -, -l, --login
          Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar
          to a real login:

             o      clears all the environment variables except TERM

             o      initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL,
                    USER, LOGNAME, and PATH

             o      changes to the target user's home directory

             o      sets argv[0] of the shell to '-' in order to make
                    the shell a login shell
```

I usually think about it in terms of the environment I want, in all honesty I tend to always use `su -` by default.